# Categorizing bank statements in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to categorize a bank statement from a list of rules in excel. I've tried using a `vlookup` but I would like to be able to have a non exact matches and as far as I know `vlookup` is not suitable for this.

I downloaded my bank statements and combine them into separate sheets and want to add a category to it (to later on combine the different sheets into one pivot table/chart.

Is there a simple way to add another column using vba to the sheet "Statement" called Category that uses the rules to generate categories for each transaction?

What I want:

A VBA Macro that will read the column description, will match a keyword there from a list of many such in Sheet2, column "keywords" and then write in Column Category (sheet1) the assigned Categorization taken from Column Category on Sheet2.

I found a great thread on this but can't get it to work on my sheets:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim PatternFound As Boolean

    Call speedup

    lastrow = Sheets("Keywords").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Sheets("SOURCE DATA").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastrow2
        PatternFound = False
        j = 1
        Do While PatternFound = False And j < lastrow
            j = j + 1
            If UCase(Sheets("SOURCE DATA").Range("E" & i).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Keywords").Range("A" & j).Value) & "*" Then
                Sheets("SOURCE DATA").Range("F" & i).Value = Sheets("Keywords").Range("B" & j).Value
                PatternFound = True
            End If
        Loop
    Next i

    Call normal
End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to follow what the actual question is here.  Does your code not work?  If not, what does it do?  How is that different than what you want it to do?  Since you have explicit references to sheets and ranges, this question would benefit from a description of what the different ranges contain.  A picture might be helpful.  You can post a link and I will add it to the post proper since you don't have the rep to add pictures.  Please add these details by editing your original question.

Comment: Note that there is a `FIND` function in Excel that can find arbitrary chunks of text within other cells.  This will work in an array formula to find keywords within other cells.

Comment: hi, the acutal question is: "my data downloaded comes in rows and how can i have an (semi) automated way of additin a category label / cell to each row". I found the code above on this platform and from what i understand, it should be usable fro me, but i can't get it to work. It actually doesn't seem to do anything... don't know VBA and that's probably my biggest issue for the moment in trying to debug the above code...